# Please give an example of factory method pattern

Tags: design-patterns, factory

I read the difference between `factory` pattern and `factory method` pattern.

Factory method pattern defers instantiation of an object to subclasses. Also  it is a Factory Method because the children of “Creator” are responsible for implementing the “Create” method.

Where as a simple factory is called directly by the class which wants to create an object.

But for factory pattern also we can decouple the factory class by adding class registration through reflection and using a layer of subclasses for the objects to be created and keeping the object instantiation logic inside this subclasses.

I am not getting an example of the factory method pattern that conforms to the above definition of factory method pattern.

Can you please provide me a factory method example?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we want to produce fruits:

```
    public interface Fruit {
        public void plant();
        public void grow();
    }

    // concrete fruit Apple
    public class Apple implements Fruit {
        @Override
        public void plant() {
            System.out.println("Apple is planted.");
        }
        @Override
        public void grow() {
            System.out.println("Apple is growing.");
        }
    }

    // concrete fruit Banana
    public class Banana implements Fruit {
        @Override
        public void plant() { ... }
        @Override
        public void grow() { ... }
    }
```

In ***factory*** pattern, there is one factory class responsible for producing new instances. ***While the disadvantage is that if added one type of instance, have to change logic of the factory class***.

Example:

```
// Factory class
public class FruitGarden {
    public static Fruit createFruit(String fruitName) throws Exception {
        if(fruitName.equals("Apple")) {
            return new Apple();
        } else if(fruitName.equals("Banana")) {
            return new Banana();
        } else {
            System.out.printf("Sorry! %s not supported.\n", fruitName);
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
    /* another way to create instance
    public static Fruit createApple() {
        return new Apple();
    }
    public static Fruit createBanana() {
        return new Banana();
    }
    */
}
```

In ***factory method*** pattern, there is an abstract factory representing the creation of new instances. Different type of instances are created by different concrete factories. All these concrete factories implement the abstract factory interface or extends abstract factory class. ***If added one new type, just add one concrete factory, so it has more expandability***.

Example:

```
// abstract factory interface
public interface FruitGarden {
    public Fruit createFruit();
}

// concrete factory which is responsible producing Apple
public class AppleGarden implements FruitGarden {
    @Override
    public Fruit createFruit() {
        return new Apple();
    }
}

// concrete factory which is responsible producing Banana
public class BananaGarden implements FruitGarden {
    @Override
    public Fruit createFruit() {
        return new Banana();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks For the examples. I just have one more confusion. I have seen that  in  factory pattern also the creation of classes can be separated from the factory class. For example see this link http://www.jineshmathew.com/2013/04/factory-design-pattern-using-reflection.html . Then in that case we don't really have any difference between factory method and factory pattern.

Comment: @MadhuriM Yes, using reflection is also a way to avoid hard code object types. While if using reflection, you have to register required product classes with the factory, like `Factory.create(Apple.class);`, and using reflection may make application a bit slow because reflection is not high performance. Reflection is suggested to be used when dynamic loading external libraries or plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Java's `Collection.iterator()` is a factory method.

The concrete implementation of the collection determines what concrete iterator is returned by this method.